# Laravel - on click, pass the element id to function in the controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have been struggling with this issue for a couple of days now...
In my home view I have a group of two buttons that are linked to another controller "BookingController". these two buttons have a variable id, that changes based on the value stored in the database. So what I wanna do is when the user click the first button "start button" a new record will be added in the "booking" table in database and one of the values that will be sotred in this record is the id of the element clicked. The problem is I can't figure a way to pass this id to the controller where I will use it in "addBooking" function. I would like to pass the id value to the function as a whole and modify the string in the controller function itself or after modifying it as a string here in the javascript.

here is the code simplified

`

```
@php
    use App\Http\Controllers\BookingController;
@endphp

@push('js')
<script> 
        function reply_click(clicked_id)
        { 
            if (clicked_id.indexOf(startTime) !== -1)
            {   
                var roomID= clicked_id.replace("btnStart","");
               ** var booking = " <?php BookingController::addBooking(); ?> ";**  <---- I want to pass the "roomID" var into "addBooking" function here
            }
            else if (clicked_id.indexOf(endTime) !== -1)
            {
                var roomID= clicked_id.replace("btnEnd","");
                var booking = " <?php BookingController::updateBooking(); ?> ";             
            }
        }
</script>
@endpush

@section('content')
<div class="btn-group">

<button onClick="reply_click(this.id)" id="btnStart{{ $room->id }}" type="button"></button>
<button onClick="reply_click(this.id)" id="btnEnd{{ $room->id }}" type="button"></button>

</div>
@endsection
```

`

I tried couple of ways but still not getting the value passed. I tried the cookies and it's working but it keeps adding the same record on each reload. I also tried the following

`$.post ('app\Http\Controllers\BookingController.php', {room: roomID});`

`$.ajax ({ type: 'post', url: 'app\Http\Controllers\BookingController.php', data: {room= roomID}, sucess: function (data)  { console.console.log(data);} });`

Comment: " still not getting the value passed" - what does that mean? You cannot call PHP functions directly in JS, you need AJAX for this

Comment: Remember that PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, javascript after. This means that `var booking = " <?php BookingController::addBooking(); ?> ";` will run on load, not on click. You'll want to use ajax to submit the form, and with ajax, you can pass the room ID

Comment: I used ajax and still nothing, I wrote the code so i don't know what I am doing wrong. I wrote the ajax I used at the end

Comment: The URL would be wrong in your ajax. You need to point the URL to the route, not to the path of the class. It won't be accessible.

Comment: If you wrote some AJAX code, please also add the controller action you are using

Comment: @aynber thanks, the problem was with the url indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'app\Http\Controllers\BookingController.php' is not a url. Use a valid url to point to your controller method.

Your ajax code should be something like this. I don't know what your route looks like, so point to the correct route.

```
$.ajax ({ method: 'post', url: '/booking/update', data: {room: roomID}, success: function (data)  { console.log(data); } });
```